# Conjugacy class's cardinalities' property.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

The question is like this: group $G$ has an order of $p^e*m$ for some prime $p$. ($m$ coprime $p$) Then G must contain an element g with the order of $p$ and $\# Cl(g)$ divides m.

Intuitively, there seems something to do with the Sylow theorem. However, after some trying, it's surely more than that.

Comment: what is $Cl(g)$?

Comment: The Conjugacy class of g in G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $G$ has an element of order $p$ follows from Cauchy's Theorem, but we can do better: $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^e$, and we know that $p$-groups have nontrivial center. So $G$ has a subgroup $P$ of order $p^e$, and en element $g\in P$ of order $p$ and such that $g\in Z(P)$: $g$ commutes with every element of $P$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: From this point, I can get the $Cl(G)$ in P is a set with only itself, meaning no element belongs to P conjugates with this g. Am I right? I guess I need to find out this class's size is p or some power to p.

Comment: @qwertymask:  No; you get that the $P$-conjugates of $g$ are just $g$, but you aren’t just looking at $P$-conjugates, you are looking at $G$-conjugates. That is, not just $xgx^{-1}$ with $x\in P$, but you must do it for $x\in G$.

Comment: I know... I just confused about how the P-conjugates can help me with the G-conjugates... But get nothing for almost an hour...

Comment: The number of elements of the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$ is the index of the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. If the centralizer contains $P$, then what can you say about its index?

Comment: Well, I don't know there is such a theorem. However, this is where I stuck, because I can't assure that the centralizer only contains P, then what I can say is the index is at least $p^e $. But it is not good enough. Did I miss something?

Comment: “Such a theorem” is the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, and in any case, if you’ve ever proven the class formula, you’ve used it. You don’t need the centralizer to be just $P$, because you aren’t trying to prove that the size of the conjugacy class *is* $m$, you are trying to prove that the size of the conjugacy class **divides** $m$.

Comment: Well... I still can't figure it out... I must miss something very important. How "containing" this $P$ can help me. It requires divisibility however I can't even find a  math relationship...

Comment: @qertymask: Yes, you are missing some rather basic and important things. Like the fact that the centralizer contains $P$ and is a subgroup, so if $P\leq C_G(g)\leq G$, then $[G:C_G(g)][C_G(g):P] = [G:P] = m$.

Comment: Thank you so much. What I forgot is a finite subgroup of some finite group, the index is always ... Well, the subgroup's degrees divide the group's... This is very basic...